# How to include external automake/autoconf projects into ament_cmake?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I'm porting a package from ROS1 to ROS2 that builds and exposes a 3rd-party project to the ROS world. That external library uses automake and autoconf, and I do not want to change that to stay compatible with upstream provider of the lib. In the past, I used the cmake macro `ExternalProject_Add` to do this. Now, I am having trouble porting this functionality to ament_cmake.

My initial questions are:

1. What is the preferred way to build, install, and export 3rd-party non-cmake source projects for ament_cmake?
2. Has anybody successfully compiled, installed, and exported such an library using `ExternalProject_Add`?

I will refine my questions, once the issue has become clearer. ;)

For reference, this is the catkin CMakeLists that I want to port to ROS2: [CMakeLists](https://github.com/code-iai/iai_robot_drivers/blob/master/igh_eml/CMakeLists.txt)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333125/how-to-include-external-automake/autoconf-projects-into-ament_cmake?/) by [Georg Bartels](https://answers.ros.org/users/2542/georg-bartels/) on ROS Answers with karma: 157 on 2019-09-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-16**:\

> In the past, I used the cmake macro `ExternalProject_Add` to do this. Now, I am having trouble porting this functionality to ament_cmake.

I would actually expect this to still be the preferred way to do this in ROS 2 (as essentially 'nothing' has changed afaik).

At least on `github.com/ros2`, the `*_vendor` packages use `ExternalProject_Add(..)` quite a bit. See [ros2/yaml_cpp_vendor/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/ros2/yaml_cpp_vendor/blob/7b13e97a4facb5a68515827c278a1a63fdb4ae5d/CMakeLists.txt) for instance.

It would be good if you could describe the issues you encountered with `ExternalProject_Add` in your ROS 2 port.

**Comment by [Georg Bartels](https://answers.ros.org/users/2542/georg-bartels/) on 2019-09-17**:
@gvdhoorn Thank you for the fast response and the link to yamlccp. That looks great! I will provide a more detailed description of my issues. For the moment, we continued work by making our own debian for the upstream library, and installing that on the system.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-09-17**:
Another possible option would be to implement a `colcon-automake/autoconf` extension which invokes these tools directly. That would avoid the need to use CMake / `ExternalProject`. It would require more effort for the first package but any following packages would work out-of-the-box. Feel free to ask questions if you want to go that route. E.g. `colcon-cmake` is also just an extension to support CMake based packages in colcon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After some months, I am revisiting this question, and I found a solution. For completeness sake, I post my solution here. It turned out that using `ExternalProject_Add` was still the easiest solution, after all.

The package contains only CMakeLists.txt, package.xml, readme, and license files.

Relevant parts of package.xml:

```
<buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>
<depend>autoconf</depend>
<depend>libtool</depend>
```

The CMakeLists looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(igh_eml)

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(upstream_igh_eml    # Name for custom target
  #--Download step--------------
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/ribalda/ethercat.git
  #The following TAG should correspond to the same version as your installed kernel modules
  GIT_TAG 7d73d5b2b372b37b95ce5d7bf16aa5b032190004
  TIMEOUT 30           # Time allowed for file download operations
  #--Update/Patch step----------
  UPDATE_COMMAND touch <SOURCE_DIR>/config.h COMMAND mkdir -p <SOURCE_DIR>/include <SOURCE_DIR>/lib    # Source work-tree update command
  #--Configure step-------------
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND touch <SOURCE_DIR>/ChangeLog COMMAND autoreconf -i <SOURCE_DIR> COMMAND <SOURCE_DIR>/configure --prefix=<INSTALL_DIR> --disable-kernel --enable-hrtimer --enable-tool  # Build tree configuration command
  #--Build step-----------------
  BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1         # Use source dir for build dir
  #--Install step---------------
  INSTALL_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"  # Installation prefix
  BUILD_COMMAND cd <SOURCE_DIR> COMMAND make -j8
)

install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})

ament_export_include_directories(include)
ament_export_libraries(ethercat)
ament_package()
```

For understanding: `ethercat` is a library built by that project and it resides in `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib` after `ExternalProject_Add` completed. Headers are in `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include` after the macro. I was surprised that `ament_export_include_directories(include)` actually did the right thing even though I neither specified an absolute path nor is there such a directory in the source repository.

---

Originally posted by [Georg Bartels](https://answers.ros.org/users/2542/georg-bartels/) with karma: 157 on 2020-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0